# How to prevent HTML code from running?

Tags: javascript, html, performance, processing-efficiency

I seek to embed multiple iframes on a single page without slowing the page. When I embedded a single iframe, it was running smoothly; added a second and third, and all were slower - despite only one being displayed at a time (using JScript). I presume this is due to the iframe code still executing.

How can I execute code conditionally? In my case, whenever a button is clicked.

Help is appreciated.

---

Fiddle for the exact code I use, with actual content replaced by IDs and iframes by p's: http://jsfiddle.net/aof89Ljt/55/

**HTML** for the iframes:

```
<p id="ifr1">
  ifr1
</p>
<p id="ifr2" style="display:none;">
  ifr2
</p>
<p id="ifr3" style="display:none;">
  ifr3
</p>
```

**UPDATE:** New JFiddle link with JScript included. End-goal description: I click a button which displays a different embedded Desmos graph, then another graph, then the first graph - in a loop, one at a time (see code). Demonstration gif: https://puu.sh/Bjpil/da9a038e11.gif

**UPDATE 2:** Solution found; full code: https://jsfiddle.net/32uxrhmw/49/

**UPDATE 3:** Greatly optimized code: https://jsfiddle.net/32uxrhmw/92/

Comment: so you mean you are showing first iframe only, and one button click or on some event you are hiding first iframe, and showing the second one, and so on?

Comment: better to put your iframes on data attribute of the element and when you click the button you get it from the data attribute and set it as the innerHTML of the element.

Comment: Correct @DeepakSharma

Comment: Unsure how that'd work @Muhammad

Comment: My updated answer shouldn't slow initial load time because the url value is only added to source onclick. It may need tweaking to include a loop, but that is a different question.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon - I think you are new here, so just so you know it is generally considered poor form to keep expanding the scope of you enquiry. People give up their time to answer you, and then you change the playing field. In future, you should try break your issues down to single issues and post them separately - eg 1) initial page load issue with iFrames, 2) your 'looping' effect etc. As to the looping effect, how are you doing it - loading a gif like in your example? If so, you probably just want to load the image in the same format I have suggested for iframes.

Comment: Your answers should also be separate answer posts with the code here on the site instead of updates to the question that are just 3rd party links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `onclick="<your function>"` event trigger to the element(s) you want to "do something".

Simple example:

```html
<button onclick="swap()">Button</button>

<iframe style="display: none;" data-url="https://www.example.com" id="iframe">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
  
<script>
function swap() {
e = document.getElementById('iframe'); // get iframe
url = e.dataset.url; // get desired url attribute stored in data-url
e.setAttribute("src", url); // add the iframe src with desire url
e.removeAttribute("style"); // remove styling that hid it otherwise
}
</script>
```

UPDATED to better apply to question.

UPDATED again to also incorporate @Joe Fitzsimmons good suggestion re handling iframe sources (in his answer).

FINAL ADDITION SEEING YOUR CODE:

Looking at your last code, it seems what you want to do is:

1. load page with one iframe;
2. then change iframe displayed when the button is clicked.

If that is what you want, you might want to use this much simpler code:

(Note: I used your code sample as a base, but haven't inserted any src urls - yours may be private, but even if not they all showed the same result so it may confuse other readers)

```
<style> 
.tdropbtn {
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #0066CC;
}
</style>

<center>
<iframe id="frame" src="https://url1" width="500px" height="400px" frameborder=0></iframe>
</center>


<div style="display:inline;">
  <center>
    <button onclick="swap()" class="tdropbtn">[+]</button>
  </center>
</div>

<script>
var counter     = 1;
var firstFrame  = "https://url1";
var secondFrame = "https://url2";
var thirdFrame  = "https://url3";
var e           = document.getElementById("frame");

function swap() {
if (counter == 0){
    e.src = firstFrame;
    counter++;
}
else if (counter == 1){
    e.src = secondFrame;
    counter++;
}
else if (counter == 2){
    e.src = thirdFrame;
    counter = 0;
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: Notepad++ does not recognize 'data-url' to be a valid HTML attribute - and the iframe no longer renders. Furthermore, what's the point of setting the url in a function when it appears to be set in the iframe?

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon - this is a normal attribute pattern and will work in browsers. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon - if you run the code, the iframe is revealed. It is hidden initially so you do not get an ugly empty square. It is not set in the src attribute of the iframe because that will cause it to load when the page loads - which is what you wanted - i.e. not slowing down initial page load, and only loading when button is clicked.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon - Nearly. the `data-url` is the place to store the url value. So put the url up there where you have #, not in the function. Where you had the url in the function, replace that with "src" (with the quotes) - that got it working for me.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon - Also, just as an aside, you should probably avoid using the `<center>` element - while still supported by browsers, it is an obselete element (see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center). Instead, just style the elements directly using wrapper elements only if needed.

Comment: I made it work - thank you for your response. In addition, I used "removeAttribute("src")" on the non-displaying iframes. Full code: https://jsfiddle.net/32uxrhmw/49/

Comment: Excellent code simplification - applied: https://jsfiddle.net/32uxrhmw/92/  As a side question, how would I center the iframe without <center>? text-align and margin auto don't seem to do anything.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon - Depending upon your objective, either style it directly and/or wrap it in a `<div>` and add styles to that. Basically, these days best practice is to keep html and styles separate. To center, I'd probably add a class to a `div` wrapper with the property `margin: 0 auto;`.

Answer (score 0):

One idea would be to load/remove the source of the iframe onClick.

This is a rough idea of what you could do:

```
function Swap(id, url) {
 document.getElementById(id).src = url;
}
```

You'd have to show and hide the iFrames as well.  Hopefully this could get you on your way.  I'm not exactly sure what your end goal is.